# Programatically add an image in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

I am new to the web development world , I would like to know if there is a way I can programatically;

- display an Image
- hide/delete an Image

I need to do so by clicking on a button ( a button for each action )

any ideas?

Comment: You are looking for JavaScript.

Comment: javascript and jquery are both the easiest way to go...and knowing one of them or both  is pretty much mandatory for any high-level development...so you should learn one or both of them

Comment: @IlanBiala jQuery IS javascript... I would hardly call jQuery mandatory.

Comment: for what he is asking about...there is no possible css use for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can do it easily. Here is a small example:

```
<p><center><button style="background:url('someImage.jpg');width:86px;height:45px"       onclick="Test()"></button></p>
<div><img id="img1"  style="visibility:hidden" src="test.jpg" width="768" height="1280" />    </div>
<script>
function Test(){
    document.getElementById('img1').style.visibility='visible';
}
```

You can alter values in visibility to `hidden` to hide the image.

[This can be a good place for you to start!](http://www.proglogic.com/learn/javascript.php)

Comment: visibility: hidden hides the image but keeps its spot on the page...while visibility: none deletes the image from the page and reorganizes it...be careful which you use

Comment: Thanks Alot , this is exactly what I need :)

@IlanBiala Thank you for your feedback , do you have a suggestion on how to delete the image from memory (don t want to go through memory leaks issues)

Comment: html doesn't have serious problems with memory when you are doing simple things....you usually don't have to worry about that and anyway you should really give a specific scenario, your questions are too vague for me to help you...